# next js prisma undefined when in vercel deployment

Tags: node.js, next.js, prisma, vercel

So...I have an api in Next js that uses Prisma Client. Prisma is imported from the global object defined in prisma.ts

Locally everything builds and runs fine. I get no errors and the prisma variable is defined.
However, when it's deployed in Vercel, prisma is undefined...I can't work out why.

If anyone has any suggestions, I'd much appreciate it.

```
import eBayApi from "@hendt/ebay-api";
import prisma from "../../lib/prisma";

const eBay = new eBayApi({});

export default async (req, res) => {
  // Access the provided 'page' and 'limt' query parameters
  const code = req.query.code; // this is provided from eBay
  console.log(code);

  try {
    //const token = await eBay.OAuth2.getToken(code);
    const token = "bob";

    console.log("Prisma handler instance", prisma);

    const env_variable = await prisma.variable.upsert({
      where: {
        variable: "EBAY_TOKEN",
      },
      update: { value: token },
      create: {
        variable: "EBAY_TOKEN",
        value: token,
      },
    });

    if (env_variable) {
      console.log("New Token Stored in DB");
    } else console.log("Failed to store new Token");

    res.status(200);
    res.writeHead(302, {
      Location: "/orders",
      //add other headers here...
    });
    res.end();
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
    res.status(400).end();
  }

  res.writeHead(302, {
    Location: "/orders",
    //add other headers here...
  });
  res.end();
};
```

> 2021-04-18T19:06:18.680Z  869eb228-423a-4d6a-b05a-f95f5e843c88    ERROR   TypeError:
> Cannot read property 'upsert' of undefined
> at exports.modules.5712.**webpack_exports**.default (/var/task/nextjs-store/.next/server/pages/api/success.js:55:126)
> at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
> at async apiResolver (/var/task/nextjs-store/node_modules/next/dist/next-server/server/api-utils.js:8:1)
> at async Server.handleApiRequest (/var/task/nextjs-store/node_modules/next/dist/next-server/server/next-server.js:67:462)
> at async Object.fn (/var/task/nextjs-store/node_modules/next/dist/next-server/server/next-server.js:59:492)
> at async Router.execute (/var/task/nextjs-store/node_modules/next/dist/next-server/server/router.js:25:67)
> at async Server.run (/var/task/nextjs-store/node_modules/next/dist/next-server/server/next-server.js:69:1042)
> at async Server.handleRequest (/var/task/nextjs-store/node_modules/next/dist/next-server/server/next-server.js:34:504)
> at async Server. (/var/task/nextjs-store/___next_launcher.js:26:9)

Comment: The error is saying "upsert" is undefined, not Prisma. "prisma.variable.upsert" specifically. Is that the right name?

Comment: It's 'upsert of undefined' i.e. cannot read the valid upsert of the undefined object prisma.variable

The upsert is correct as far as i can tell, and being used elsewhere

https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/prisma-client-reference#upsert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I had a play around, and think I found the problem. My prisma table field was a VARCHAR (String), however I was inadvertently trying to store upsert with a JSON object.
Now that I've changed to a JSON field it's working.

So I guess the only problem is that maybe the error wasn't helpul?
Although it was all my stupid fault.